# Download 1 blob from 200 containers

Tags: node.js, azure, typescript, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have got more than 200 containers and I need to download 1 blob from every container. If I will download each blob in loop it's take a lot of time. For this reason I decided to download blobs parallel.

```
let testFunctions = [];

containers.array.forEach( container => {
  testFunctions.push(
        (callback) => {
            that.blobService.getBlobToText(container, 'container/' + date, (error: any, blob: any) => {
                if (blob!== null) {
                    callback(null, blob);
                } else {
                    callback(error, null);
                }
            });
        }
    )
});

async.parallel(testFunctions, async (error, blobs) => {
          //Todo
});
```

But after some requests I have got this error:

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 1.2.3.4:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1087:14)
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '1.2.3.4',
  port: 443 } ,
```

Can you help me to solve this problem or do you know another way how can I fast download blobs frome more than 200 containers?

P.s. I'm using azure-storage V 2.3.0 & nodejs

Comment: Are you running your code locally on your machine or hosted on Azure (App Service Plan)?

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET on local machine.